# How do I display outcome in my textEdit box from application

Tags: python, designer, pyqt6

Im trying to display the conversion of currency in my textEdit widget. I converted my .ui to .py and am using radioButtons to select currencies, I can input my number and select my currencies but it wont display the calculated outcome
Here is the last bit of my code not including setup_ui:

```
 def convert_currency(self):
    conversion_rates = {
    "$ US":1.0,
    "GB P":0.72,
    "Euro":0.85,
    "Yen":112.54,
    "Peso":20.15,
    "Krona":8.47
}
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.convert_currency)
    selected_currency = self.radioButton.currentText()
    conversion_rate = conversion_rates.get(selected_currency, 1.0)
    latte_cost = 3.50
    cost_in_selected_currency = latte_cost * conversion_rate
    self.result_label.setText(f"cost of latte:{cost_in_selected_currency}{selected_currency}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: If that's all your complete code (excluding imports), it's not valid, as that function is never called from anywhere else. If that function is part of a class, and that class is `Ui_Form`, your case is still not valid, as editing pyuic generated files is considered bad practice (as suggested by the warning in the comment on top of those files). Please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). Note that the connection must be created *outside* of the function that will be eventually called by the signal, not inside.